# android auto boot (BOOT_COMPLETED receiver) is denied

Tags: android, boot, android-broadcastreceiver

Currently the BOOT_COMPLETED receiver is working fine with 2 emulators (Nexus5 /API25 and Nexus6/API23). However, it fails to start on my phone (Lenovo Vibe Shot Z3, android 6.0.1, API 23).

From the logcat, I found below reasons. I noticed there are also some other apps got the same refusal and those apps are not up on reboot either. However, a few apps like QQ/WeChat (they are not system app) are up after reboot. All apps are installed in internal memory.

Anyone knows how to unblock the Security_PermControlService so the boot receiver is working after reboot like QQ does?

```
 10-11 19:44:32.248  1620  1799 D Security_PermControlService: refuse
 auto boot = xxx.apk1 10-11 19:44:32.248  1620  1799 D
 Security_PermControlService: handleCheckCase
 checkResult=false;packageName=xxx.apk1;code=17;uid=0;pid=0 10-11
 19:44:32.248  1620  1799 D SecurityManagerUtils: deny pn=xxx.apk1
 action=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

**Update:**

Finally I found the vendor's setting tool for enabling auto boot. After it's turned on, everything works fine.